# $BASHPID ничего не возвращает

Tags: bash, shell, процесс

Ничего не могу понять, если я ввожу в консоли`echo $BASHPID`, то все норм, но когда тоже самое я прописываю в файле, то ничего не выводится((

содержание файла (*test*):

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $BASHPID
```

если в файле заменить $BASHPID на $PPID, то все выводиться нормально.

**bash 4.4.19(1)-release**

Answer (score 0):

Для тех 4-х человек, которые просмотрели этот вопрос и кому возможно стало интересно: Файл со скриптами я всегда вызывал с помощью команды `sh [script]`. Вызвав ман по этой команде, я обнаружил, что он отсылает совсем не к моему любимому bash, а к dash-у. Собсна на этом все.